# What is logic behind this?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

If, 1111 = r

2222 = t

3333 = e

4444 = n

5555 =?

What is the output of 5555?
What calculation needed to calculate alphabet behind 5555?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> Y. Just take the last letters after adding them.

Answer (score 8):

> Y

Because

> 1+1+1+1=4 fouR
>  2+2+2+2=8 eighT
>  3+3+3+3=12 twelvE
>  4+4+4+4=16 sixteeN
>  5+5+5+5=20 twentY